# animating a marshmallow burning

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials, node-editor, physics

I am trying to animate a marshmallow burning in a flame.  I am working on the flame right now and am about to start trying to animate it and am wondering how to animate color changes.  The marshmallow is going to start white and I want it to change to a golden brown color, then catch on fire and change black.  I'm new to blender and have done a couple little animations but those have all kept everything the same color, and I was wondering if it is possible to fade from one node to another somehow.

Comment: you can make keyframes  in the nodes for the color. So if you are at the beginning of your timeline you can set the color to white and hit I to insert a keyframe. Then some frames later you can change that color to golden brown and hit I to insert a keyframe. Maybe you then have to change the interpolation mode (T) in the graph editor.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know you could do that for nodes too.  I knew you could do it for location, rotation and scale, but didn't know you could for nodes, thanks!

Comment: @gladys This didn't work for me. Does this keyframe rule still stand in Blender 2.28? If not, is there another way to do this?